# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a queryset of unique values. Here is my model

```
class Data_agent_account(models. Model):

    data_agent = models.ForeignKey(Data_agent, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    type = models.BooleanField(null=False)  # debit=False & credit=True
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    paid_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_entered', ]
```

In my view, I'm trying for

```
da_list = Data_agent_account.objects.filter(paid_on__isnull=True).order_by('data_agent').distinct('data_agent')
for da in da_list:
    print(da)
```

The error I get is :

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
> LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("data_agent_data_agent_account"."data_ag...

The SQL that works is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(data_agent_id) FROM data_agent_data_agent_account WHERE paid_on is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
da_list = Data_agent_account.objects.filter(paid_on__isnull=True).values_list('data_agent', flat=True).distinct()
```

`da_list` it's a queryset of the unique `data_agent_id` values.

more info about `values_list` here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

Comment: The distinct does not work. I get a queryset with a lot of duplicates. I'm not sure if .duplicate() works after the queryset is flattened?

Comment: I guess I'll add ```da_unique = set(da_list) ```

Comment: version with set() will work, but it will be an extra workload for memory usage. if `da_list` will contains thousands or millions of `id` values, that will cause a problem.